# calling Contradicting function from inside div

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I didn't really knew how to put this, but basically I have a div that calls a toggle function and it is inside a div. i wanted the wrapper div to be able to call a contradicting function.

```
<div id="slide" onclick="closeMenu()>
<div class="header">
    <div id="menu" onclick="toggleMenu()"></div>
</div>
```

and my js

```
function toggleMenu(){
if(document.getElementById("slide").style.left == "250px") {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.left = "0px";
} else {
    document.getElementById("slide").style.left = "250px";
}
}

function closeMenu(){
    document.getElementById('slide').style.left = 0;
}
```

the idea is that div "menu" will toggle the menu on and off and every other place (div "slide" is as big as the entire screen) will close the menu.
but then nothing works.

Comment: So what is the problem? Does this not work?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I think your problem is event propagation. [Read here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). Basically you need to make sure that child div event doesn't get fired on parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all cache your slide for simplicity and faster access

```
var slide=document.getElementById('slide');
```

Are you using modern browsers/mobile browsers ? then use css

```
#slide{
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;height:100%;
 left:0%;
 top:-100%;
 background-color:pink;
}
#slide.active{
 top:0%;
}
```

then add the following eventlisteners to the menu and the slide.

```
menu.addEvnetLitener('click',toggle,false);
slide.addEvnetLitener('click',toggle,false);
```

and create the eventhandler `toggle`

```
function toggle(e){
 slide.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

if the slide is active, cliking it will remove the class and so close the slide, clicking the menu button will add the class or remove it.

`classList` has also the following functions:

```
add,remove,contains

function add(e){
 slide.classList.add('active');
};

var isTheSlideClassActive=slide.classList.contains('active');
```

those steps above are simple and allow you a good control over your dom elements.it also allows you to change the whole css class for the slide.without touching later the js code.

if you need support for older browsers your approach is ok, but you need to add more checks.
as mentioned by **Салман** the problem could be the overlapping of the 2 clickable elements.in that case you need to stop the propagation..

the old way to do this is to return false.

but i think some browsers are unable to stop the propagation with a click as alot of stuff happens before the click event is fired, for example touch devices, so you have to use on mousedown or mouseup....

example old:

```
slide.onmouseup=function(e){/*do stuff*/ return false};
```

new

```
slide.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){e.stopPropagation()},false);
```

which means that your final function would be

```
var slide=document.getElementById('slide'),menu=document.getElementById('menu');
menu.addEvnetLitener('mouseup',toggle,false);
slide.addEvnetLitener('mouseup',toggle,false);
function toggle(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 slide.classList.toggle('active')
};
```

or (old way)

```
var slide=document.getElementById('slide'),menu=document.getElementById('menu');
menu.onmouseup=toggle;
slide.onmouseup=toggle;
function toggle(e){
 var st=slide.style;
 st.left=(st.left=='250px'?0:250)+px;//short way to write what you have written.
 return false
};
```

you can do this also without javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/KLXMw/

with animations and delay

http://jsfiddle.net/RAu8Q/5/

or create complex accordions.

http://jsfiddle.net/YjCbM/1/

If you have any questions just ask.there may be some errors as i wrote this right now...without testing.

*as you don't see the slide you don't need a second function to hide it.

Comment: Thanks! I got it under control.